# How do I extract more than one timeseries from a multivariate zoo object?

Tags: r, zoo

If I have a multivariate `zoo` object:

```
z <- zoo(cbind(foo = rnorm(5), bar = rnorm(5), baz = rnorm(5)))
```

I know I can extract a single timeseries from it with the `$` operator:

```
z$foo
```

But how do I extract some, but not all timeseries? For example, if I wanted a timeseries with only `foo` and `bar`? I know I can do

```
z[, 1:2]
```

but is there another way that does not depend on the column order? I know I can also do

```
z[, c("foo", "bar")]
```

but I was hoping there would be something more elegant.

Comment: what is exactly wrong with the options you listed?

Comment: @mtoto the first will break if the column order changes; the second form is okay I guess if there's no other way...

Comment: `methods(class=class(z))` does not suggest any straight-forward getters, so it seems that the second approach is the most elegant